# Internet Explorer: HTML entities in URL

Tags: javascript, php, html, internet-explorer, url

I have got the following PHP code:

```
echo "<input type='image' src='myImage.png' onClick='javascript:location.href = \"index.php?p=1&copy=true\"' />";
```

If I click on the image, Chrome redirects to `index.php?p=1&copy=true`. But if I click on the image in Internet Explorer 11, it redirects to `index.php?p=1©=true`.

Internet Explorer seems to replace HTML entities in URLs.

I tried using `&amp;` instead of `&`, but I got the same problem: IE replaces it into the copyright symbol.

How can I use `&copy` in my URL?
I know that one possible solution would be to replace `&copy` with `&whatever`, but than I must change my hole system.

There are also other people with the same problem:

https://gist.github.com/pguillory/5136408

Comment: *"I tried using &amp; insted of &, but I got the same problem: IE replaces it into the copyright symbol."* Can you show us an example of that? Because that's the right way to do it. Remember: Attribute value text is HTML text, so named entities are parsed.

Comment: Note that you don't use `javascript:` on `onxyz` attributes, only where URLs are expected. So you wouldn't want it above (it's harmless, though; the JavaScript engine just thinks it's a labelled statement).

Comment: @T.J.Crowder: Your `onclick='location.href = "index.php?p=1&amp;copy=true"'` doesn't work. IE 11 replaces the `&amp;copy` to `©`.

Comment: Ugh, replicated it: http://jsbin.com/dajihiwiwo/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The correct version is with the `&amp;`. Sadly, though, IE11 does indeed have a Big Old Bug in it causing it to take `&amp;copy` and turn it into the copyright symbol.

I found a workaround: Percent-encode the `c` in `copy`:

```
echo "<input type='image' src='myImage.png' onClick='location.href = \"index.php?p=1&amp;%63opy=true\"' />";
// --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------^^^
```

Example of the correct version that nevertheless fails on IE11: http://jsbin.com/dajihiwiwo/

Example of the above (which is also correct, just more obtuse) which works on IE11: http://jsbin.com/nehuxazeka/

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried your code, but IE 11 redirects me to `index.php?p=1&%63opy=true`. You jsbin link works in IE 11. Perhaps duckduckgo makes something different?

Comment: @Pengxer: Yup. Just tried it with a domain that does *nothing* with the query string, and IE11 leaves the %63 there. Which it shouldn't do. Lovely.

Comment: @Pengxer: That said: `index.php?p=1&%63opy=true` is canonically the same as `index.php?p=1&copy=true`. Was PHP not giving you a `copy` value in `$_GET`?

Comment: Yes, you are right. I only looked at the URL and compared it with your duckduckgo example and find the difference. But your code works and `$_GET['copy']` (in PHP) is set. Thank you!

Comment: I think this is the accepted answer because it is a real solution (workaround) of my problem. Look at _LooInSpain_ answer, if you need a simple solution. It only works if you have got other variables than html entities.

Answer (score 3):

Why not just swap the variables?

Instead of `index.php?p=1&copy=true` it should still work with `index.php?copy=true&amp;p=1`.

Comment: Nice, pragmatic solution that will work in this case.

Comment: Thanks for you answer. It worked for me. But there will still be a problem if you are using only html entities in your URL. But this is (actually) not my problem :D